# 2 years work experience on resume but no skills

Tags: career-development

I have been in corporate office for nearly two years but did not work a single day. Initially, when I was in an agency since there were no clients I had no work, this continued and I got irritated and decided to switch to a client role. When I switched to the client role there is no work as there are multiple agencies doing the entire work now!! On my resume, it says I know digital marketing but I do not have real hands-on experience. I have recently started freelance projects but that is also slow.

Please tell me what I should do, I have no skills and hate my current job. I am scared for my future

Comment: What did you do while in the office for two years?

Comment: Matthew, I did the internal work like creating the checklist on the basis of which the websites were analyzed, did the presales work which meant making pitch decks for getting businesses, did the reporting work, currently i maintain reports and do the admin work, like raising purchase orders even though i was hired for digital marketing

Comment: You helped run your agency. Experience and skill with business processes, sales, and administration are rare. Good organizers are harder to find than web devs. Please don't sell yourself short.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to use your real name here

Answer (score 6):

> I have been in corporate office for nearly two years but did not work a single day.

This is false, as demonstrated by your comment:

> I did the internal work like creating the checklist on the basis of which the websites were analyzed, did the presales work which meant making pitch decks for getting businesses, did the reporting work, currently i maintain reports and do the admin work, like raising purchase orders even though i was hired for digital marketing

You may have not been doing the work you were hired for, but you were doing work nonetheless, and (from your description) a lot of that was at least tangentially related to digital marketing.

I would suggest forming the bulk of your job description (in your CV) around those activities that were related, emphasising the digital marketing aspects as much as possible without lying. I'd also suggest mentioning "other responsibilities" for things like raising POs briefly as well - that's a role that signifies trust, and is a useful skill that many other employers may also value.

It may not be an ideal situation, but it's nowhere near as dire as you're making out - don't sell yourself short!

Comment: Hi Berry, Thanks for replying to my query.  So as per your suggestion, I should change my role from digital marketing to business process and operations?